# Any Chance of null pointer exception?

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

Is it possible under any scenario for the following code to throw a NullPointerException?

Say for example we have the function `testFunction` of class `myClass` that declares a variable and returns it without initializing it first:

```
public static String testFunction()
{
  String s1
  return s1
}
```

and we then had the following code that compares the return value to a String:

```
String myString = myClass.testFunction();

if(myString == "test")
{
 system.out.println("Print A")
}
else
{
 system.out.println("Print B")
}
```

I think it would always print "Print B" unless the function actually returned "test" and then it would print "Print A".  Would this be correct?

Comment: in java there is some `;` at the end of each command ...

Comment: @pzaenger in which case it certainly will throw an NPE...

Comment: You can safely try it, neither java nor you computer  will break.

Comment: `myClass` can be null, so call to testFunction can cause NPE

Comment: use `"test".equals(myString)` to avoid the null pointer error while comparing.

Comment: @IlyaBursov testFunction is a static member, so it initialized by default.

Comment: @Tezra you want to say that `myClass` is not instance, but class name?

Comment: @IlyaBursov `public static String testFunction()` The static means you reference it by class, not instance. So myClass should be a class name.

Comment: This code will not print a null pointer exception because it does not contain anything like System.out.println("null pointer exception").  However, this says absolutely nothing as to whether this code may, or may not, ***throw*** a null pointer exception.

Comment: `Would this be correct or is there any chance at all that a null pointer exception could be thrown?` @MikeNakis read the question again.

Comment: @Jones5672 Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your question to try to increase clarity. If my edits changed the meaning of your question, please let me know and we'll fix it.

Comment: @Tezra well, luckily, it has been edited.

Comment: You're both right. :P Before editing, the question said "print a null pointer" at the start and "null pointer could be thrown" at the end. Hopefully it's clearer now while retaining the essence of the original query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as you've written this it can't produce an NPE (for multiple reasons).

```
public static String testFunction()
{
  String s1;
  return s1;
}
```

This will result in a compiler error because `s1` has not been initialized. I added semi-colons to your code sample to make it syntactically valid.

```
if(myString == "test")
```

This will not produce an NPE. However, it is also not the proper way to compare Strings for equality. The proper way to see if two String objects are the same sequence of characters is `firstString.equals(secondString)`, which can produce an NPE if `firstString` is null.

When comparing a String literal to a variable that could be null, a common idiom is to put the String literal first, since it is a known non-null object, like this:

```
"test".equals(myString);
```

This will never produce an NPE.

Comment: Thanks to you and everyone else who contributed with an answer and thank you for your very detailed answer.

Comment: Also, one side question, just for my own knowledge.  In the above example if(myString =="test") so even if myString is null it still wouldnt cause a null pointer exception?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The `==` operator used with objects compares object quality, meaning, more or less, "are these both pointers to the same object?" It's the difference between equality and sameness. If I have a yellow rubber duck and you have the same model of yellow rubber duck, our ducks are equivalent (`myDuck.equals(yourDuck)`) but they are not the same (`myDuck != yourDuck`).